# Replace only one duplicated word

Tags: php, replace

Is it possible to replace only one word in a sentence even if this word is repeated many times:

```
<?php
$sentence 'Hello my name is Abu Rayane, my age is 99 yearsl old, and my school level is -1';
$new_sentence = str_replace('my', '__', $sentence);
echo $new_sentence;
?>
```

I would like to replace the first 'my' ONLY.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [the manual](http://php.net/str_replace) has the answer, do a careful reading :-)

Comment: I could not find any

Answer (score 2):

Use this :http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php, with $limit parameter.

Comment: I used the below example, but it is replacing both my, 1st and second, while putting in delimiter 2

Answer (score 1):

AlexDeb is correct.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$sentence = 'Hello my name is Abu Rayane, my age is 99 yearsl old, and my school level is -1';
$new_sentence = preg_replace('/my/', '__', $sentence, 1);
echo $new_sentence;
?>
```

Comment: yes, if I put 2, the output is: Hello __ name is Abu Rayane, __ age is 99 yearsl old, and my school level is -1